# How to drive flyback transformer with digital input?

Tags: transformer, flyback, gate-driving

I'm building a DSP PWM plasma speaker and using a push-pull to drive a TV flyback transformer:

[image]

- This circuit is not flyback but it works. However I'd like to properly drive the flyback transformer instead.
- Any comments/suggestions to the circuit is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What converter topology do you want to use? Without the capacitor, a DC voltage across the transformer primary will cause a large DC current.

Comment: No it won't work without C3 so leave it in. It's not a flyback circuit BTW. If it were it could operate without C3 (and Q2).

Comment: @Andyaka Could you please show me how to modify this to a proper flyback circuit ?

Comment: Flyback is what happens from a SPST  when opened V=LdI/dt, you have a SPDT push pull so it transforms  rather than flyback. But then you cannot use a 60V switch

Comment: the flyback open circuit allows flux to equalize so it doesn't saturate and become a short like your test without a cap. The DC  current integrated from DC voltage can saturate the core and L goes to 0, but not a pulse that is opened. The flyback reverses the voltage greatly as current returns to zero

Comment: @7E10FC9A no I can't because to design a flyback circuit you need to know what the load is, how it might vary in value, what the output ripple needs to be below and how you will control the circuit to achieve regulation. Your circuit gives no clue as to what you really want in terms of performance so no, there's nothing I can add to help you other than this: design is driven by performance and functional goals and not about how you might achieve those goals.

Comment: You changed the title but you are still “locked in” into an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/). Your circuit is not a flyback but rather a half-bridge. My recommendation is that you take two steps back, try to build a buck or flyback converter from scratch and learn. Simulations are very helpful too.

Comment: find the schematic of the TV the flyback came from. Then drive it the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *proper* way to drive a flyback transformer is to drive it into saturation from the low voltage side —as much flux as possible—, then cut the driving current and let the high voltage side try to sustain the current from the flux.

You don't want that in your speaker application as it creates horrible distortions.